# How to use babel query + custom plugin with HappyPack 3.1.0

Tags: webpack, babeljs

How would I convert this loader to use happypack?

```

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          // NamespaceTransform converts the requires in legacy zukeeper code calls to 
          //  App.namespace() to commonJs requires 
          plugins: [NamespaceTransform],
          // TODO : upgrade Uglify + webpack to support direct es6 minification and remove
          //   es2015 preset.  Uglify doesn't recognize import and export statements
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2', 'react']
        }
      },
```

```

I've tried putting it in several different places.

The `NamespaceTransform` is a custom babel transform plugin required above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your babel config in a separate file since it can't be serialized to JSON (because of NamespaceTransform.) So, first move that config to a file named `.babelrc`.

```js
// @file .babelrc
module.exports = {
  plugins: [NamespaceTransform],
  presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2', 'react']
}

// @file webpack.config.js
{
  module: {
    // rework your loader so that it points to happypack's:
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'happypack/loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ]
  },

  // now define the HappyPack plugin
  plugins: [
    new HappyPack({
      loaders: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            // tell babel to read the config from .babelrc
            babelrc: true
          }
        },
      ]
    })
  ]
}
```

A simpler approach where you won't need to use `.babelrc` is that you stop passing `NamespaceTransform` as an object/function but instead pass its package name as a string and babel will just pick it up. That would be like `plugins: [ 'babel-namespace-transform-plugin' ]` if that's the name of the npm package.

**Edit**: the alternative solution also works for packages that are not on NPM, in that case you simply pass the absolute path (e.g. using `path.resolve()`) to the plugin's directory and babel should pick it up as well.